# Why is Wiremock server not picking correct stubbing with similar URL but different REST operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, wiremock

I have an integration test that ends up making two API calls to the same service. One is a GET call, and the other is a PUT. When it calls the GET, it works just fine, but when it calls the PUT, it doesn't find a matching request and throws an exception.

The userService in the below example is a WireMock Server

Here is my stubbing

```
private void stub() {
    userService.stubFor(
            get(urlPathEqualTo("/api/v1/users/" + userId))
                    .willReturn(
                            aResponse()
                                    .withStatus(200)
                                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "close")
                                    .withBody(
                                            "{"
                                                    + "\"id\": \""
                                                    + userId
                                                    + "\","
                                                    + "\"name\": \""
                                                    + userName
                                                    + "\""
                                                    + "}")));
    userService.stubFor(
            put(urlPathEqualTo("/api/v1/users"))
                    .willReturn(
                            aResponse()
                                    .withStatus(200)
                                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "close")));
}
```

The exception that ends up being thrown from the PUT call is

> Caused by: org.springframework.retry.RetryException: Could not
> recover; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver
> class
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient does
> not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method
> 'abstract org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance
> choose(java.lang.String,
> org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.Request)' of interface
> org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.ServiceInstanceChooser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561504/open-feignclient-integration-with-netflix-ribbon-not-working-in-springboot

Comment: I never heard about OpenFeign before, and the person in that post did receive the same error I did, but it doesn't seem relevant to my issue. Probably both have the same underlying issue, but there could be many reasons why this exception would be thrown. I'm trying to figure out why my specific use case is causing this exception